# Завершение программы в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать раннее завершение программы в Python? В самоучителе я нашёл несколько примеров:

```py
exit(0)
sys.exit
os.abort()
```

Однако, там не было объяснения какой метод лучше. Какой метод является наиболее "безаварийным"?

И заодно: есть ли в Python понятие Autocloseable объектов? Если я сделаю ранее завершение программы, нужно ли мне будет закрывать файлы и т.д.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used

Comment: Спасибо!
Лучшим решением является использование sys.exit()

Comment: на счет второго: лучше закрывать/завершать все операции перед завершением программы

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Короткий ответ:
Лучше использовать [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit)

---

Механизм завершения процесса в Python реализован через бросание исключения [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit), таким образом можно просто создать подобное исключение и программа завершится:

```
raise SystemExit
# или даже передать число -- код ошибки завершения программы
raise SystemExit(1)
```

Функция `exit` и аналогичная ей `quit` созданы для удобства работы в интерактивном режиме и их не рекомендуется использовать внутри скриптов:

> They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs.

По факту они также просто поднимают исключение, и при попытке вызова без скобок напишут подсказку о правильном способе выхода из интерпретатора:

```
>>> quit
Use quit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit
>>> exit
Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit
```

Использовать `sys.exit` стоит потому, что эта функция лежит в стандартном модуле и будет всегда там доступна. Также это довольно явный способ выразить своё желание завершить программу.

Есть также дополнительный метод для немедленного завершения программы: [`os._exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit). У него довольно специфическая область применения, и там же есть замечание:

> The standard way to exit is `sys.exit(n)`

Т.е. здесь даётся подтверждение того, что стандартный способ завершения программы -- это вызов `sys.exit`.

Функция [`os.abort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.abort), упомянутая вами, использует механизм сигналов процессу. Конкретно при вызове этой функции будет передан сигнал [`SIGABRT`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGABRT), что в linux приведёт к завершению программы и созданию [дампа памяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8) процесса. Подобное завершение рассматривается операционной системой как аварийное, поэтому не стоит использовать его для безаварийного завершения приложения.

---

По второй части вопроса. В Python есть развитая система контекстных менеджеров: классов, которые умеют работать с оператором `with`. Самое частое использование этого механизма встречается, вероятно, с файлами.

```
with open('filename') as my_file:
    print(my_file.read())
```

Этот код откроет файл, напечатает его содержимое на экран и закроет файл автоматически, даже если возникнет исключение при его печати.

Для классов, которые не приспособлены для работы с `with` есть функция [`closing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) в библиотеке `contextlib`. Из документации:

> Code like this:
>
> ```
> with closing(<module>.open(<arguments>)) as f:
>     <block>
> ```
>
> is equivalent to this:
>
> ```
> f = <module>.open(<arguments>)
> try:
>     <block>
> finally:
>     f.close()
> ```

Вот небольшой пример работы этой функции:

```
import contextlib

class Closeable:
    def close(self):
        print('closed')

with contextlib.closing(Closeable()):
    pass

# печатает closed
```

---

Теперь небольшое отступление о том, почему стоит использовать конструкцию `with`.

Известно, что программа завершится от любого необработанного исключения, а не только от `SystemExit`. Таким образом, если в вашем коде используются какие-то ресурсы, которые требуется правильным образом закрывать перед завершением работы, нужно оборачивать работу с ними в блоки `try ... finally ...`.

Однако, при использовании конструкции `with` это оборачивание происходит автоматически, и все ресурсы закрываются корректно.

Так как выход из программы -- это всего лишь брошенное исключение, то и в случае использования функции `sys.exit` закрытие открытых в операторе `with` ресурсов произойдёт корректно:

```
with contextlib.closing(Closeable()):
    sys.exit()
# напечатает closed
```

Вы можете писать также и свои классы, предоставляющие ресурсы или классы, оборачивающие другие, которые нужно уметь закрывать автоматически. Для этого используются методы `__enter__` и `__exit__`.

---

Источники:

1. Похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used) с англоязычного StackOverflow
2. [Функции, добавляемые модулем site](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module)
3. Документация [по конструкции `with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)
4. Документация по функции [`closing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing)
5. Документация по исключению [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit)
6. Документация по функции [`os._exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit)
7. Документация по функции [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit)
8. Документация по функции [`os.abort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.abort)
9. Описание системного сигнала [`SIGABRT`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGABRT)

Comment: Пример применения: 1. не использовать ничего (завершение с успехом по окончанию программы) 2. `sys.exit(__doc__ % dict(prog=sys.argv[0]))` напечатать usage, если неправильные аргументы коммандной строки даны 3. `os._exit(1)` если надо из дочернего потока программу завершить (atexit обработчики не вызываются, файловые буфера (включая stdout) могут потеряться). 4. `os.abort()` пракически никогда не следует вызывать, SIGABRT указывает на баги в программе.

Answer (score 0):

```
#python 2
def sigint_handler(signum, frame):
    print(os.getpid())
    print 'CTRL + C/Z Pressed, app is now killed!'
    os.kill(os.getpid(),9)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)
```