# Как проверить несколько значений переменной оператором if?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Привет! Работаю над большим проектом. Но свой вопрос объясню на другом
>   примере...

Допустим мне нужно создать программу которая только умеет выходить из себя)

Но пользователь может написать по разному слово "выход", например, "ВЫХОД", "VYHOD", "Выход", "выход" или "ds[jl"(на раскладке 'латиница')и т.д.

Тогда код бы выглядел примерно так

```py
vyhod = input('Введите слово "выход" для выхода из программы:')
if vyhod == 'выход':
    exit(0)
if vyhod == 'Выход':
    exit(0)
if vyhod == 'ВЫХОД':
    exit(0)
```

и так далее...

Так вот, как можно это всё дело сократить.
Например, я пробовал сделать так:

```
if vyhod == "выход", "Выход", "ВЫХОД":
    exit(0)
```

и так

```
if vyhod == "выход"; "Выход"; "ВЫХОД":
        exit(0)
```

> но это invalid syntax)

Comment: Вы можете значительно упростить себе задачу: `input('Введите цифру "0" для выхода из программы:')` ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Можно так:

```
if vyhod in ["выход", "Выход", "ВЫХОД"]:
    exit(0)
```

Но вообще, лучше привести строку к нижнему регистру и проверять только 1:

```
if vyhod.lower() == "выход":
    exit(0)
```

Comment: Еще можно проверять несколько условий с помощью оператора `or`, например, `if a or b or c:`, где a, b, c - выражения сравнения. Но варианты @Felucca24 самые оптимальные

Comment: @ZaArs самые оптимальные – слишком громкое заявление. Как минимум `vyhod in ("выход", "Выход", "ВЫХОД")` будет всегда работать быстрее варианта со списком, а `vyhod in {"выход", "Выход", "ВЫХОД"}` в ряде случаев будет еще быстрее.

Comment: Ок. Тогда, как уж пошло на предирки, то вероятно, `a = {'выход': exit, 'ВЫХОД': exit, ... }; a[input_str]() тоже быстро отработает

Comment: @extrn на трёх строковых элементах разница будет незначительной. Заметной разницы между поиском по кортежу и по списку скорее всего не будет.

Comment: @extrn вот кстати замеры: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz2Xy.png

Comment: @insolor незначительная, я бы сказал крохотная, но есть. Выигрыш не в поиске, а в формирования коллекции. Кортеж констант загружается одной инструкцией, список из 3х элементов - четырьмя.

Comment: @extrn, разница от десятых долей до единиц наносекунд, really? На практике при поиске в короткой последовательности без разницы, что у вас - list, tuple или set. Вот еще один замер, list "рвет всех" на 0,2 наносекунды (на целых 0.3%)! https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUZiH.png

Comment: @insolor на таких объемах данных я бы не полагался на точность замеров :) Поймите правильно, я изначально поставил плюс ответу. Меня всего лишь смутила формулировка "самый оптимальный"

Comment: @extrn, мы рассматриваем не сферический абстрактный вариант в вакууме, а вполне конкретный пример из ответа. Вы утверждаете, что tuple **всегда** будет быстрее варианта со списком, а set еще быстрее (в ряде случаев). Я отвечаю - для коротких последовательностей, в том числе для данного примера, замена list на tuple или set не даст хоть какого-то достоверно измеримого прироста производительности. Поэтому *в данном случае* все три варианты равноправны. На этом предлагаю закончить)

Comment: @insolor В этом выражении python не использует список вообще. Он оптимизирует выражение, заменяя список на кортеж, генерируя при этом идентичный [код](https://ideone.com/1Tqak8). Так что соглашусь - результаты не просто схожи, они одинаковы. Но будь список/кортеж сформирован отдельно, [разница](https://ideone.com/snn0U4), в том числе во времени работы, была бы более заметной.

Answer (score 2):

```
exit = ['Выход', 'DS{JL', 'выход']

word = 'Выход'

for i in exit:
    if i == word:
        print("Валим")
```

Заводишь все возможные значения в list и пробегаешь по ним в цикле.

Answer (score 1):

```
if vyhod == 'выход' or vyhod == 'Выход' or vyhod == 'ВЫХОД':
    exit(0)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

## [Завершение программы в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459170/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B2-python)

```
def ask_for_exit(ask: str, exit_words: list):
    if input(ask).lower().strip() in map(str.lower, exit_words):
        raise SystemExit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit_words = ["выход", 'exit']
    ask_for_exit(f'Для выхода из программы, введите одно из слов {exit_words} в любом регистре:', exit_words)
    print('работа')
```